# Trying to install Android SDK

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

Installing fine, however getting this error when trying to view available packages....

> android sdk failed to fetch url reason: Invalid argument: connect

Any ideas?

Comment: In settings section try to check checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that Android SDK Manager does *NOT* like java 7 update 1. I uninstalled java 7 and used java 6 update 27 and I am able to connect just fine and get the packages.

I don't know what it is but give that a shot for people having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I Ran in to this same problem when they came out with the newest version of the platform tools. they changed the repository address. or in more plain terms, they changed the address of the update server between now and the last time you updated so now the updater can't find the server.  What I had to do is uninstall the sdk, and download a new starter package and install that. Also I found the new starter package demands the most current JDK so if you like me haven't updated that recently do that first!

myself I had to rip out the SDK,the JDK, and Eclipse download new installers and reinstall them all to get the update to work properly.